# Cannot Create Salesforce Dashboard Pages

Tags: reporting, dashboard, salesforce-lightning

I'm new to Salesforce platform hence this might be a really stupid question.

I followed below mentioned article to create a new page in Dashboard but couldn't (the '+' button is not visible)

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_dashboard_pages.htm&type=5

Below is a screenshot of my dashboard builder (Please note I have system admin privileges)
[image]